# Problems during Load

Tags: csv, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfml

After running the following code, at the time of generating CSV output in excel file, I'm getting following error:

```
Problems during Load:
Missing file:  C:\CFIDE\scripts\ajax\resources\yui\yui.css
Missing File: C:\CFIDE\scripts\ajax\resources\cf\cf.css
```

The code I'm running is as follows:

```
<CFHEADER NAME="Content-Disposition" VALUE="inline; filename=stats.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel"><cfoutput>#Query2Excel(qONEQUERY)#</cfoutput>
```

Here is the [Query2Excel](http://cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=560) function:

```
function Query2Excel(query) {
    var InputColumnList = query.columnList;
    var Headers = query.columnList;

    var AlternateColor = "FFFFFF";
    var header = "";
    var headerLen = 0;
    var col = "";
    var colValue = "";
    var colLen = 0;
    var i = 1;
    var j = 1;
    var k = 1;

    var HTMLData = "";

    if (arrayLen(arguments) gte 2) {
        Headers = arguments[2];
    }
    if (arrayLen(arguments) gte 3) {
        InputColumnList = arguments[3];
    }

    if (arrayLen(arguments) gte 4) {
        AlternateColor = arguments[4];
    }
    if (listLen(InputColumnList) neq listLen(Headers)) {
        return "Input Column list and Header list are not of equal length";
    }

    HTMLData = HTMLData & "<table border=1><tr bgcolor=""C0C0C0"">";
    for (i=1;i lte ListLen(Headers);i=i+1){
        header=listGetAt(Headers,i);
        headerLen=Len(header)*10;
        HTMLData = HTMLData & "<th width=""#headerLen#""><b>#header#</b></th>";
    }
    HTMLData = HTMLData & "</tr>";
    for (j=1;j lte query.recordcount;j=j+1){
        if (j mod 2) {
            HTMLData = HTMLData & "<tr bgcolor=""FFFFFF"">";
        } else {
            HTMLData = HTMLData & "<tr bgcolor=""#alternatecolor#"">";
        }
        for (k=1;k lte ListLen(InputColumnList);k=k+1) {
            col=ListGetAt(InputColumnList,k);
            colValue=query[trim(col)][j];
            colLength=Len(colValue)*10;
            if (NOT Len(colValue)) {
                colValue="&nbsp;";
            } 
            if (isNumeric(colValue) and Len(colValue) gt 10) {
                colValue="'#colValue#";
            } 
            HTMLData = HTMLData & "<td width=""#colLength#"">#colValue#</td>";
        }
    HTMLData = HTMLData & "</tr>";
    }
    HTMLData = HTMLData & "</table>";

    return HTMLData;
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: None of the code that you posted seems to relate in any way to the "error" you're reporting. Where are you seeing this error? It's not a CF error. I think you're not telling us about some key bit of this.

Comment: I'm getting a window with caption : Problems on Load and then the information about the missing files is written over there.Yeah, it's not a CF error.

Also, can you tell me how can I make sure the above file is downloaded only when a user click on Download button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generated HTML needs to use http references to the CSS files. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/yui/yui.css">
```

Of course the css file nees to be in the appropriate directory